# Neo4j Cypher query with null or not null value

Tags: neo4j, spring-data, cypher, spring-data-neo4j

In my Spring Data Neo4j project I have a following entities:

```
@NodeEntity
public class Decision extends Commentable {

    private final static String CONTAINS = "CONTAINS";
    private final static String DEFINED_BY = "DEFINED_BY";

    private String name;

    @Relationship(type = DEFINED_BY, direction = Relationship.INCOMING)
    private Set<CriterionGroup> criterionGroups = new HashSet<>();

    @Relationship(type = DEFINED_BY, direction = Relationship.INCOMING)
    private Set<Criterion> criteria = new HashSet<>();

...

}

@NodeEntity
public class Criterion extends Authorable {

    private final static String CONTAINS = "CONTAINS";
    private final static String DEFINED_BY = "DEFINED_BY";

    private String name;

    @Relationship(type = CONTAINS, direction = Relationship.INCOMING)
    private CriterionGroup group;

    @Relationship(type = DEFINED_BY, direction = Relationship.OUTGOING)
    private Decision owner;

...

}

@NodeEntity
public class CriterionGroup extends Authorable {

    private final static String DEFINED_BY = "DEFINED_BY";
    private final static String CONTAINS = "CONTAINS";

    private String name;

    @Relationship(type = DEFINED_BY, direction = Relationship.OUTGOING)
    private Decision owner;

    @Relationship(type = CONTAINS, direction = Relationship.OUTGOING)
    private Set<Criterion> criteria = new HashSet<>();

...

}
```

I have a following SDN repository method:

```
@Query("MATCH (d:Decision)<-[:DEFINED_BY]-(c:Criterion) WHERE id(d) = {decisionId} and c.name = {name} RETURN c")
Criterion findCriterionDefinedByDecisionByName(@Param("decisionId") Long decisionId, @Param("name") String name);
```

Based on this query I can get `Criterion` that belongs to `Decision` and have a specific name.

Criterion in my domain model may (or may not)belong to `CriterionGroup`.

I need to extend this query in order to add one more condition for checking `CriterionGroup` associated with this Criterion. In another words I need to return Criterion with a specific {name} for a specific {decisionId} that belongs(or not in case of null value) to a provided {criterionGroupId}. In case of {criterionGroupId} == null I need to find Criterion that do not belong to any `CriterionGroup`.

I need something like this:

```
@Query("MATCH (d:Decision)<-[:DEFINED_BY]-(c:Criterion)...????????...... WHERE id(d) = {decisionId} and c.name = {name} RETURN c")
Criterion findCriterionDefinedByDecisionByName(@Param("decisionId") Long decisionId, @Param("name") String name, @Param("criterionGroupId") Long criterionGroupId);
```

Please help me to write this query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work, and shouldn't be too slow either unless you have tens of thousands of `CriterionGroups` per `Criterion`:

```
MATCH (d:Decision)<-[:DEFINED_BY]-(c:Criterion)
WHERE id(d) = {decisionId} 
  AND c.name = {name}
OPTIONAL MATCH (c)<-[:CONTAINS]-(cg:CriterionGroup)
WITH c, extract(g IN collect(cg) | id(g)) AS cgIds
WHERE CASE
        WHEN {criterionGroupId} IS NULL THEN size(cgIds) = 0
        ELSE {criterionGroupId} IN cgIds
      END
RETURN c
```

Alternatively, you could have 2 methods in your `Repository`, to manage each case directly, using

```
MATCH (d:Decision)<-[:DEFINED_BY]-(c:Criterion)
WHERE id(d) = {decisionId} 
  AND c.name = {name}
  AND NOT (c)<-[:CONTAINS]-(:CriterionGroup)
RETURN c
```

when `criterionGroupId` is null, and

```
MATCH (d:Decision)<-[:DEFINED_BY]-(c:Criterion),
      (c)<-[:CONTAINS]-(cg:CriterionGroup)
WHERE id(d) = {decisionId} 
  AND c.name = {name}
  AND id(cg) = {criterionGroupId}
RETURN c
```

otherwise.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I'm going to have a single CriterionGroup(not thousands!) associated with a single  Criterion(but I'm going to have thousands of Criterion, Decision and CriterionGroup). One CriterionGroup can have a few tens of Criterion. So in this way from performance point of view is it safe to use the solution number one with a single query ?

Comment: You'll be traversing _from_ the `Criterion` _to_ 0 or 1 `CriterionGroup`, there shouldn't be a performance problem with the single query.